# Convenient complexity for Stream API usage?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, code-complexity

I have JSON document which is a result of parsing for a bunch of files:

```
{
  "offer": {
    "clientName": "Tom",
    "insuranceCompany": "INSURANCE",
    "address": "GAMLE BONDALSVEGEN 53",
    "renewalDate": "22.12.2018",
    "startDate": "22.12.2017",
    "too_old": false,
    "products": [
      {
        "productType": "TRAVEL",
        "objectName": "Reiseforsikring - Holen, Tom Andre",
        "name": null,
        "value": null,
        "isExclude": false,
        "monthPrice": null,
        "yearPrice": 1637,
        "properties": {}
      }
    ]
  },
  "documents": [
    {
      "clientName": "Tom",
      "insuranceCompany": "INSURANCE",
      "fileName": "insurance_tom.pdf",
      "address": "GAMLE BONDALSVEGEN 53",
      "renewalDate": "22.12.2019",
      "startDate": "22.12.2018",
      "issuedDate": "20.11.2018",
      "policyNumber": "6497777",
      "products": [
        {
          "productType": "TRAVEL",
          "objectName": "Reiseforsikring - Holen, Tom Andre",
          "name": null,
          "value": null,
          "isExclude": false,
          "monthPrice": null,
          "yearPrice": 1921,
          "properties": {
            "TRAVEL_PRODUCT_NAME": "Reise Ekstra",
            "TRAVEL_DURATION_TYPE": "DAYS",
            "TRAVEL_TYPE": "FAMILY",
            "TRAVEL_DURATION": "70",
            "TRAVEL_INSURED_CLIENT_NAME": "Holen, Tom Andre, Familie"
          }
        },
```

I want to iterate throug all `products` from `documents` section and set missed `properties` to `products` from `offer` section.

Offer and documents at the same depth level at JSON.

Implementation for this with Stream API is following:

```
private void mergePropertiesToOffer(InsuranceDocumentsSession insuranceSession) {
    Validate.notNull(insuranceSession, "insurance session can't be null");
    if (insuranceSession.getOffer() == null) return;

    log.info("BEFORE_MERGE");
    // merge all properties by `objectName`
    Stream.of(insuranceSession).forEach(session -> session.getDocuments().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(doc -> doc.getProducts().stream())
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(docProduct -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(docProduct.getObjectName()))
            .filter(docProduct -> MapUtils.isNotEmpty(docProduct.getProperties()))
            .forEach(docProduct -> Stream.of(session.getOffer())
                    .flatMap(offer -> offer.getProducts().stream())
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(offerProduct -> MapUtils.isEmpty(offerProduct.getProperties()))
                    .filter(offerProduct -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(offerProduct.getObjectName()))
                    .filter(offerProduct -> offerProduct.getObjectName().equals(docProduct.getObjectName()))
                    .forEach(offerProduct -> {
                        try {
                            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
                            log.info("BEFORE_PRODUCT: {}", mapper.writeValueAsString(offerProduct));
                            offerProduct.setProperties(docProduct.getProperties());
                            log.info("UPDATED_PRODUCT: {}", mapper.writeValueAsString(offerProduct));
                        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                            log.error("Error converting product to offer: {}", e.getCause());
                        }
                    })));
    log.info("AFTER_MERGE");
}
```

It works fine. However, implementing is much faster than maintaining in the future.

There two times I am using `Stream.of()` factory method for getting a stream for 2 entities at a different level. Also, `flatMap()` is used as much as possible, + all null checks.

***And the question isn't this implementation too difficult?***

Should it be refactored and divided into smaller parts? If yes how it should be with good programming principles?

**SOLUTION:**

Huge thanks to `nullpointer` answer.
Final solution is following:

```
Map<Integer, InsuranceProductDto> offerProductMap = session.getOffer().getProducts()
    .stream()
    .filter(this::validateOfferProduct)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InsuranceProductDto::getYearPrice, Function.identity(), (first, second) -> first));

Map<Integer, InsuranceProductDto> documentsProductMap = session.getDocuments()
    .stream()
    .flatMap(d -> d.getProducts().stream())
    .filter(this::validateDocumentProduct)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(InsuranceProductDto::getYearPrice, Function.identity(), (first, second) -> first));

documentsProductMap.forEach((docPrice, docProduct) -> {
    if (offerProductMap.containsKey(docPrice)) {
        offerProductMap.compute(docPrice, (s, offerProduct) -> {
            setProductProperties(offerProduct, docProduct);
            return offerProduct;
        });
    }
}); 
// after finishing execution `offerProductMap` contains updated products
```

Comment: implementation seems to be too difficult, but it can refactored.

Comment: @SagarP.Ghagare Any suggestion how it should be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start off with, you can create a common `Predicate`s for those chained filters as

```
.filter(offerProduct -> MapUtils.isEmpty(offerProduct.getProperties()))
.filter(offerProduct -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(offerProduct.getObjectName()))
.filter(offerProduct -> offerProduct.getObjectName().equals(docProduct.getObjectName()))
```

you can write a `Predicate` such that

```
Predicate<OfferProduct> offerProductSelection = offerProduct -> MapUtils.isEmpty(offerProduct.getProperties())
                                    && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(offerProduct.getObjectName())
                                    && offerProduct.getObjectName().equals(docProduct.getObjectName());
```

and then simply use that as a single filter

```
.filter(offerProductSelection);
```

By the way, you could have preferably moved that to a method returning `boolean` and then used that in the filter.

---

Not precise for the sake of data types and utility classes used, but for the sake of representation, you could do something like :

```
private void mergePropertiesToOffer(InsuranceDocumentsSession insuranceSession) {
    Validate.notNull(insuranceSession, "insurance session can't be null");
    if (insuranceSession.getOffer() == null) return;
    Map<String, InsuranceProductDto> offerProductMap = insuranceSession.getOffer().getProducts()
            .stream()
            .filter(this::validateOfferProduct)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(InsuranceProductDto::getObjectName, Function.identity())); // assuming 'objectName' to be unique

    Map<String, InsuranceProductDto> documentsProductMap = insuranceSession.getDocuments()
            .stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(d -> d.getProducts().stream())
            .filter(this::validateDocumentProduct)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(InsuranceProductDto::getObjectName, Function.identity())); // assuming 'objectName' to be unique

    Map<String, Product> productsToProcess = new HashMap<>(documentsProductMap);
    productsToProcess.forEach((k, v) -> {
        if (offerProductMap.containsKey(k)) {
            offerProductMap.compute(k, (s, product) -> {
                Objects.requireNonNull(product).setProperties(v.getProperties());
                return product;
            });
        }
    });

    // now the values of 'offerProductMap' is what you can set as an updated product list under offer
}


private boolean validateDocumentProduct(InsuranceProductDto product) {
    return Objects.nonNull(product)
            && MapUtils.isNotEmpty(product.getProperties())
            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(product.getObjectName());
}

private boolean validateOfferProduct(InsuranceProductDto offerProduct) {
    return Objects.nonNull(offerProduct)
            && MapUtils.isEmpty(offerProduct.getProperties())
            && StringUtils.isNotEmpty(offerProduct.getObjectName());
}
```

---

***Edit***: Based on the comment,

> objectName can be the same for a bunch of products

you can update the code to use the merge function as:

```
Map<String, InsuranceProductDto> offerProductMap = insuranceSession.getOffer().getProducts()
        .stream()
        .filter(this::validateOfferProduct)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(InsuranceProductDto::getObjectName, Function.identity(), 
                     (a,b) -> {// logic to merge and return value for same keys
                            }));
```

Comment: @nazar_art My bad, I meant abstracting out that relevant logic into single function specific for the tasks. Both the chains of `filter` for example. And should have used the terms *Encapsulation* then.

Comment: Good solution. Only I want to add that `objectName` can be the same for a bunch of products. Therefore, it fails with `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key`. Is it possible to find some workaround for that?

Comment: @nazar_art you can use the merge function within the `Collectors.toMap` overload. See the edit.

Comment: validators are a little bit different. For `offer` product it should check `MapUtils.isEmpty(offerProduct.getProperties())`. For document product, it should be opposite.

Comment: @nazar_art got it, rollbacked with the update. On the other hand, I hope anyway you're now aware of what I was suggesting initially.

Answer (score 1):

For each session, all offer products's properties will refer to the last qualified document product's properties, right ?

Because the inner stream will always evaluate to the same result independently of the current document product.

So, while rectifying this, i will suggest the following refactor :

```
final class ValueWriter
{
    private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    static
    {
        mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    }

    static String writeValue(final Object value) throws JsonProcessingException
    {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(value);
    }
}

private Optional<Product> firstQualifiedDocumentProduct(final InsuranceDocumentsSession insuranceSession)
{
    return insuranceSession.getDocuments().stream()
        .filter(Objects::notNull)
        .map(Document::getProducts)
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .filter(docProduct -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(docProduct.getObjectName()))
        .filter(docProduct -> MapUtils.isNotEmpty(docProduct.getProperties()))
        .findFirst()
    ;
}

private void mergePropertiesToOffer(final InsuranceDocumentsSession insuranceSession)
{
    Validate.notNull(insuranceSession, "insurance session can't be null");

    if(insuranceSession.getOffer() == null) return;

    log.info("BEFORE_MERGE");

    final Optional<Product> qualifiedDocumentProduct = firstQualifiedDocumentProduct(insuranceSession);

    if (qualifiedDocumentProduct.isPresent())
    {
        insuranceSession.getOffer().getProducts().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(offerProduct -> MapUtils.isEmpty(offerProduct.getProperties()))
            .filter(offerProduct -> StringUtils.isNotEmpty(offerProduct.getObjectName()))
            .filter(offerProduct -> offerProduct.getObjectName().equals(qualifiedDocumentProduct.get().getObjectName()))
            .forEach(offerProduct ->
            {
                try
                {
                    log.info("BEFORE_PRODUCT: {}", ValueWriter.writeValueAsString(offerProduct));
                    offerProduct.setProperties(qualifiedDocumentProduct.get().getProperties());
                    log.info("BEFORE_PRODUCT: {}", ValueWriter.writeValueAsString(offerProduct));
                }
                catch (final JsonProcessingException e)
                {
                    log.error("Error converting product to offer: {}", e.getCause());
                }
            })
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution missed some important places. I don't need to get only the first product from the document's products. I need all products and compare them with `objectName` from offer products. And if properties are empty or null for offer product -> set it from document one which has the same odbject name.

Comment: @nazar_art, are the object names amongst document and offer products unique ?

Comment: they are unique for `products`. However, they can have duplicates from different documents.